# JavaFX - Slim images to prevent overloading the heapspace?

Tags: javafx, imageview, heap-memory

[image: Image library on the left side]
Due to programming an Image Viewer with JavaFX I implemented an image library with following structure:

**HBox** - **ScrollPane** - **VBox**

This is the basic structure, the library objects are constructed as following:

**StackPane** - **ImageView** - **Label**

Because there's no `setAlignment` method for `ScrollPane`, I put the whole thing in a `HBox`, even though I don't need the other features of it.

These methods are responsible for the generation and initialization of the library:

```
private HBox createScrollableLibrary()
{
    libraryContent = new VBox();
    libraryContent.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    libraryContent.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    libraryContent.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent");
    libraryContent.setSpacing(10);

    libraryScroll = new ScrollPane();
    libraryScroll.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
    libraryScroll.setStyle("-fx-background: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);"
                  + "-fx-background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);");
    libraryScroll.setMinWidth(135);
    libraryScroll.setMaxWidth(135);
    libraryScroll.setContent(libraryContent);

    HBox root = new HBox();
    root.setPickOnBounds(false);
    root.getChildren().add(libraryScroll);
    return root;
}
```

And:

```
public void initLibrary()
{   
    Runnable work = () -> 
    {
        ObservableList<StackPane> previewList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ImageView preview;
        Label label;
        StackPane previewAndLabel;

        for(int i = 0; i < picturePaths.size(); i++)
        {
            String path = picturePaths.get(i).toURI().toString();
            preview = new ImageView(new Image(path));
            preview.setPreserveRatio(true);
            preview.setFitWidth(100);
            //label = new Label(new File(path).getName());
            label = new Label("IMAGE");
            StackPane.setAlignment(label, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
            previewAndLabel = new StackPane();
            previewAndLabel.getChildren().addAll(preview, label);
            previewList.add(previewAndLabel);
        }

        Platform.runLater(() -> GUI.getLibraryContent().getChildren().addAll(previewList));
    };
    loading = new Thread(work);
    if(loading.isAlive())
        loading.interrupt();
    loading.start();
}
```

Info: `picturePaths` is an `ObservableList` which contains the paths of all selected images which in turn are selected with a `FileChooser`.

Now my question(s):

I know it's very inefficient to use large sized pictures as preview images.
Even though I increased my heap space to 1GB it slows down and throws a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` exception when I'm adding more pictures, I'm guessing the limit is about 20-25 of large sized pictures.
How can I "slim" a normal picture with, for example a resolution of 1920x1080 to 1024x720 ? Or is there another opportunity to make my library use small and "fast" images? And can I buffer my already "calculated" images to make my Image Viewer faster?

Appreciate any tips and help. Please critisize my code if needed!

Comment: Have you tried setting the size constraints on the preview pictures during the Image constructor and not afterwards?

Comment: Awesome! I'm a moron, didn't know the requestedWidth and requestedHeight properties are responsible for this.
Go and post using those methods as an answer and I'm gonna mark it as helpful.
Thank you :)

Comment: @JoseMartinez 's suggestion will save a lot of memory. Another optimization is to use a `ListView<Path>` (the items in the list being filesystem paths of the image) for your library, with a custom cell factory to display the images from the file. There is an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515396/javafx-listview-with-images-instead-of-strings). The advantage here is that list cells are reused as the user scrolls and the images loaded on demand, so as an image scrolls off screen it is eligible for garbage collection. (Of course, you can combine both suggestions.)

Comment: Thank you James_D !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can try setting the size constraints on the preview pictures during the Image constructor and not afterwards.